# Searching unescaped ampersands in a pseudo XML file on Neovim with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds, neovim, negative-lookbehind

I don't know how to transform / the equivalent of this negative lookahead search on Neovim.

`&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)`

When I try silver search, it is working. I want to search but only on the single file using `/`

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry I left out an important information in the title. it was actually a pseudo XML file.

I've updated the title. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: No worries! :) Though I wonder, what is a pseudo XML file? What makes it "pseudo"? Perhaps you could show a snippet of such a file too?

Comment: I'm using a dataset for sentiment analysis, this in particular:

https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~mdredze/datasets/sentiment/index2.html

Comment: I see. _"Each file contains a pseudo XML scheme"_ - seems to be lazy-talk for _"we didn't bother to do it properly_". :-) I looked in the files and don't understand why they didn't do the job with an XML encoder. My take on it would be to identify the tags and to encode everything in between in bulk so you get the same dataset, but properly encoded.

Comment: Yeah I kind of hate it when they force us to use this specific dataset. It is not clean, but it's all right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is interesting and I effectively have often troubles with
the syntax of regular expressions in *Vim* or other tools that don't
use the PCRE or common syntaxes!

Googling a bit, I found [this article about lookarounds in *Vim*](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Regex_lookahead_and_lookbehind).

As you can see, it's just a matter of syntax, again!

A negative lookahead such as `(?!amp;)` should be written `\(amp;\)\@!`.

This leads to something like this:

```
&\(\(\w\{2,6\}\|#\d\{1,6\}\|#[xX][0-9a-fA-F]\{1,6\}\);\)\@!
```

I match `&amp;`, `&apos;` with `&\w{2,6};` in PCRE, which becomes
`&\w\{2,6\};` in *Vim*'s syntax.

Tested that on this XML:

```xml
<note>
  <author>Jani</author>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <summary>Glasses &amp; sunscreen</summary>
  <body>
    Don't forget to pack your glasses & sunscreen to go to
    the beach tomorrow!
    If you forget your glasses &#x1F60E; -&gt; you'll damage your retina.
    If you don't put some sunscreen on -&gt; you'll probably get sun burnt &#127774;.
    Now, the problem is to match the ampersand in "H&M" &#128556;!
    &lt; = &#60;
    &gt; = &#62;
    &amp; = &
    &nbsp; = non-breaking space
    &iexcl; = ¡
    &cent; = ¢
    &pound; = £
    &curren; = ¤
    &yen; = ¥
    &brvbar; = ¦
    &sect; = §
    &uml; = ¨
    &copy; = ©
    &ordf; = ª
    &laquo; = «
    &not; = ¬
    &shy; = ­
    &reg; = ®
    &macr; = ¯
    &deg; = °
    &plusmn; = ±
    &sup2; = ²
    &sup3; = ³
    &acute; = ´
    &micro; = µ
    &para; = ¶
    &cedil; = ¸
    &sup1; = ¹
    &ordm; = º
    &raquo; = »
    &frac14; = ¼
    &frac12; = ½
    &frac34; = ¾
    &iquest; = ¿
    &times; = ×
    &divide; = ÷
  </body>
</note>
```

In *Vim*, you have to escape parenthesis, braces and pipes but
not square brackets! This is clearly not very readable. Perhaps
there are some extensions to make it easier to use. Just Googled
a bit and found [Perl compatible regular expressions in Vim](https://chrisarcand.com/perl-compatible-regular-expressions-in-vim/).

I've started writing myself a note about the **flavours of regular
expression engines**. It might be useful for others:

| PCRE | sed and vim | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `.` | `.` | match any char |
| `*` | `*` | 0 or n times |
| `+` | `\+` | 1 or more times |
| `?` | `\?` | 0 or 1 time |
| `^` | `^` | begin of pattern |
| `$` | `$` | end of pattern |
| `{3}` | `\{3\}` | 3 times |
| `{3,}` | `\{3,\}` | 3 or more times |
| `(regexp)` | `\(regexp\)` | Group matching "regexp" |
| `[abc]` | `[abc]` | "a", "b", or "c" |
| `[^abc]` | `[^abc]` | any char not "a", "b" or "c" |
| `\2` | `\2` | back reference of group n°2 |
| `(?: )` |  | non-capturing group |
| `(?=this-after)` | `\(this-after\)\@=` *Vim*✔️, *sed*❌ | Positive lookahead |
| `(?!not-this-after)` | `\(not-this-after\)@!` *Vim*✔️, *sed*❌ | Negative lookahead |
| `(?<=this-before)` | `\(this-before\)@<=` *Vim*✔️, *sed*❌ | Positive lookbehind |
| `(?<!not-this-before)` | `\(not-this-before\)@<!` *Vim*✔️, *sed*❌ | Negative lookbehind |

It seems that *sed* doesn't handle lookarounds, but the syntax is
very similar to *Vim* for most of the other cases.

Thanks to Friedrich's comment, *Vim* has helpful patterns to define
the start and end of a match: `\zs` and `\ze`.

You can place `\zs` anywhere in the search, *Vim* will only match
after the start. You can use both to say "find this specific pattern
and only replace a part of it". Example with this text:

```
James Bond and James Cameron are well known, but not James Tartempion.
```

If you only want to uppercase "James" followed by " Bond" or
" Cameron":

```
:s/James\ze \(Bond\|Cameron\)/JAMES/gi
```

But if you need negative lookarounds, then it might be more
complicated to write the pattern this way, as you'll probably have
to use negative character classes. In this case, I would use the
negative lookarounds to make the pattern more readable. Typically,
to uppercase all "James" which aren't followed by " Tartempion":

```
:s/James\( Tartempion\)\@!/JAMES/gi
```

#### Using Perl inside Vim

If *Vim* is installed with the *Perl* extension (my case out of
the box in *Cygwin* and *Ubuntu*), then you can simply use PCRE
regular expressions in *Vim*, typically for your problem of
ampersands that need to be converted to HTML entities:

```
:perldo s/&(?!(?:#\d{2,6}|#x[0-9a-fA-F]{2,6}|\w{2,6});)/&amp;/g
```

And for the *"James" not followed by " Tartempion"* example:

```
:perldo s/James(?! +Tartempion)/JAMES/gi
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I actually solved my problem earlier by using perl. Quite dirty and still, but something like this:
`cat my.xml | perl -ne 's/&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)/&amp;/g; print;' > my_copy.xml`

Comment: @JasperMartin: Glad you managed it with *Perl*, which is far easier, effectively. I've added some more useful information for all the other devs that might encounter the same problems. I tried to reply to your original question to solve it in *Vim*.

Comment: great thanks to your effort @Patrick Janser

Comment: If you use a lot of special characters, you might use Vim's *very magic* modifier `\v` (`:help /magic` has a table like yours) and lose the backspaces, i.e. `\(foo\)\+` becomes `\v(foo)+`. Much closer to PCREs, right? Another thing, in your table, how is *group* different from *negative lookbehind*?

Comment: @JasperMartin if you found a solution, please post an answer instead of a comment. You can accept your answer after two days.

Comment: @Friedrich: Great thanks for the `\v` magic! Yes, this helps a lot! I just tried it out but didn't manage to use the negative lookahead with the *very magic* syntax. Probably doing something wrong. I didn't find an example in the help page. Oh yes, thanks for my mistake in the table. I'll correct it.

Comment: Vim's [`:help perl-patterns`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns) might also be for you. Searching with very magic and negative lookahead should work like this: `/\v\&(amp|a lot of other stuff)@!`

Comment: @Friedrich: thanks again! Ok, my problem was that I didn't escape `&` before the negative lookahead. It's rather confusing, as `\&` seems to be the short syntax for writing `\(foo\)\@=` like this `foo\&`. I think I'll really switch to using the *perldo* command instead of trying to learn all these different syntaxes!

Comment: Suit yourself, `:perldo` is there to be used. Using `:set hlsearch` greatly facilitates writing search patterns as the matches will be highlighted while you type. I manage to remember to escape (, {, |, ? and +. I prefer to use the more simplistic `\zs` or `\ze` instead of look(ahead|behind) so that works out for me. YMMV.